# Docker npm install failing

Tags: linux, docker, npm, npm-install

I was using node 10 in my app. I was told by compliance I should use node 16. This was me previous docker file (removing env variables for privacy):

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
RUN npm install express-session
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

And the build and run process worked with no warning or issues. Now I changed the first line of the docker file for:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine3.11
RUN npm install -g npm
```

and now I get a warning about my package-lock.json being created with an older version of npm (which sounds right) and some error on the user not having the permissions to open such file:

[image]

I have two questions. Is the package.json file updated automatically or how can I make sure this file is created with the current npm version. And why am I getting the permission issues if the only change is in the node version? I also tried with the command 'npm install -g npm@9.2.0' for the other npm version but it only removed that warning. Why is my contrast not able to be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the
USER node
line and it did the trick. I am not the creator of the app so I'm not sure on what this line was doing.

Comment: USER sets the user for all the layers bellow it. Since the /home/node directory was created before setting the USER to "node" the directory in the container is owned by root, the user node will not have access to its own home directory, unless it's executed right after the FROM